# Devpartner Instrumentation for Code coverage causing linker errors

Tags: code-coverage, linker-errors, devpartner

So I've got a Visual studio 2005 solution that contains a C# project (test driver - creates exe) and 7 C++ Projects (dll's).

This solution builds fine up to this point.

I have DevPartner studio 8.2 installed. I am trying to generate test coverage on the entire solution which requires me to instrument native c++ code during builds. when I turn this DevPartner option on, the build produces linker errors.

Does anyone have experience with this?

For example:

```
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall IntLong::IntLong(class BufObjBase *,int,int,unsigned char,wchar_t const *,bool)" (??0IntLong@@QAE@PAVBufObjBase@@HHEPB_W_N@Z) X.obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker figured this out.
In case anyone else runs into this problem:

There is a dependency chain in the project between dlls, other dlls, and libraries. Under a normal build, visual studio is smart enough to find the libraries. With DevPartner inserting its instrumentation, it isn't.

Make sure all additional dependencies are explicitly specified in (properties on project getting the link error) -> Linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies.